# How to apply separate SCSS files to separate views in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm currently working on landing and login/signup pages, and am trying to apply different stylesheets to each layout. I've tried making a separate layout page for my home controller and calling it in my home controller with `layout "home"`. My `app/views/layouts/home.html.erb` file is pretty much the same as `application.html.erb`, except that I changed the stylesheet_link_tag from `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>` to `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "home" %>`. Though the styling from my login/signup pages is no longer applying to my landing page, my landing page now no longer has any of the styling given to it in my `app/assets/stylsheets/home.scss` file. Is there more I'm supposed to change in my layouts file than just the stylesheet_link_tag, or am I setting up separate stylesheets for each view improperly? If so, what's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't recommend changing this`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>`, instead, in my opinion, best way is to create a folder in `assets/stylesheets` for each controller you have. for example: i have `home_page_controller.rb` i would create a folder in `assets/stylesheets` as `home_page` then i would make a scss file e.g show. this allows me to navigate to my files easily. of course you can have your different approach but thats my take on it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and got it to work by putting `<body class="controller-<%= controller_name %>">` in my `application.html.erb` file, and placing whatever styling I wanted for my "home" views under `.controller-home`

Answer (score 0):

Since `rails generate scaffold` generates CSS and JS files with the same names as the controller you generate it might be intuitive to think that these files will only be loaded by that controller. That's not the case. They're loaded globally by default, and that's sort of the point.

Like Marv-C said, I wouldn't recommend changing `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>`. In production mode, Rails optimizes your CSS by loading all of it into a single file.

This also means you can structure your CSS documents any way you want. You can eliminate overlap between CSS documents by using sensible class and id-selectors (which you should).

If you take advantage of SASS nesting, it should be no problem at all.
http://sass-lang.com/guide